# User with uid=0 in database

Tags: 7, forms, database, users

I had to build a **form** with a **select** field populated with **all the users** registered in database. There are 10 users that I can see in `admin>people`.

To get all the users, I used `entity_load('user')`.

But in my select, I have **one empty option** in addition to my 10 users.

I checked in my database, and I found this empty UID=0 record:

[image]

I searched the Internet but I didn't find a satisfying answer. I read something about **Anonymous user** but I didn't get it.

- Is this record important?
- Does it have to be there?
- If yes, I'll do some trick to ignore it in my select.
- If not, can I just delete it?

Thank you in advance for this little trivial question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this record important?

Yes, it prevents some queries from failing if it's anonymous user who caused them.

> Does it have to be there?

There is a possibility site would stay browsable you remove it... but it would mess your login functionality and may prevent sessions from persisting.

> If yes, I'll do some trick to ignore it in my select.

Consider using [EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708). Omit UIDs lower than 1, or select only users with name, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I was pretty sure that it was there for something :D

No problem for my query, I'll just test the UID in my foreach where I populate my select's options.

PS: I can accept your answer in 4 minutes ;)

Comment: "Have to" isn't a bit strong...without the anon user record authentication/session doesn't work. It's pretty much fundamental to a working Drupal install.

Comment: @Clive better now?

Comment: I think it's fairer to say "you can still browse the site, but you can't login". Or more accurately, you can login, but that session won't persist with subsequent requests. If it's ever happened to you it's very frustrating till you work out what the problem is - then you never, ever forget it!

Comment: @Clive OK, fixed

Comment: I'm not sure if there is something different in my site (that I tested). Users can login even if the uid 0 record is missing. However, anonymous comments completely fail when uid 0 is not present. Anonymous forms worked fine as well. I'm not saying uid 0 is not necessary - in fact is is necessary. But there were no login issues when uid 0 is missing.

Comment: @AyeshK it depends - if session was initiated before user attempted to visit login form, it may get weird. Or may not. If session is created at login form opening (ie it already died earlier and is re-created), then login may work all right.